# I'm trying to call QuickBook's API on Node.Js but instead I'm getting the following error

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request, quickbooks

**CODE:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const OAuthClient = require('intuit-oauth');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
oauthClient = new OAuthClient({
    clientId: 'ABmWLisPCBmxAXMM24r7HK6wK8lWpWOlybWSinDUAkW0l3FZsj',
    clientSecret: '4SRQWIXv547bUKuyDk7xxw1YIRTLddXJA11f2zhc',
    environment: 'sandbox',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8000/callback', //We have to add callback URL to quickbooks dashboard
});
app.get('/authUri', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
   
  
    const authUri = oauthClient.authorizeUri({
        scope: [OAuthClient.scopes.Accounting],
        state: 'intuit-test',
    });
    res.send(authUri);
    // Here we start the authentication process
});

app.get('/callback', function (req, res) {
    oauthClient
        .createToken(req.url)
        .then(function (authResponse) {
            oauth2_token_json = JSON.stringify(authResponse.getJson(), null, 2);
            console.log("Token:", oauth2_token_json)
            res.send(oauth2_token_json);
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log("ERR:",e);
            res.send(e);
        });
        //Here we recieve the token succesfully or get the error. 
});

app.listen(8000,()=>{
    console.log('i am running');
});


const body = {
    "Line": [
      {
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail", 
        "Amount": 100.0, 
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
          "ItemRef": {
            "name": "Services", 
            "value": "1"
          }
        }
      }
    ], 
    "CustomerRef": {
      "value": "1"
    }
  
};

oauthClient
    .makeApiCall({
    url: 'https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/4620816365092507370/invoice?minorversion=55',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log('The API response is  : ' + response);
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
    console.log('The error is ' + JSON.stringify(e));
});
```

**Error:**

The error is:

```
{
   "authResponse":{
      "token":{
         "realmId":"",
         "token_type":"",
         "access_token":"",
         "refresh_token":"",
         "expires_in":0,
         "x_refresh_token_expires_in":0,
         "id_token":"",
         "latency":60000,
         "createdAt":1603006471243
      },
      "response":{
         "url":"https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/4620816365092507370/invoice?minorversion=55",
         "headers":{
            "date":"Sun, 18 Oct 2020 07:34:32 GMT",
            "content-type":"application/json",
            "content-length":"401",
            "connection":"close",
            "server":"nginx",
            "intuit_tid":"1-5f8bf008-0186e88168aa182213feefcf",
            "www-authenticate":"Bearer realm=\"Intuit\", error=\"invalid_request\""
         },
         "body":"{\"warnings\":null,\"intuitObject\":null,\"fault\":{\"error\":[{\"message\":\"message=BadRequest; errorCode=003202; statusCode=400\",\"detail\":\"Missing required parameter: access_token\",\"code\":\"3202\",\"element\":null}],\"type\":\"VALIDATION\"},\"report\":null,\"queryResponse\":null,\"batchItemResponse\":[],\"attachableResponse\":[],\"syncErrorResponse\":null,\"requestId\":null,\"time\":1603006472539,\"status\":null,\"cdcresponse\":[]}",
         "status":400,
         "statusText":"Bad Request"
      },
      "body":"{\"warnings\":null,\"intuitObject\":null,\"fault\":{\"error\":[{\"message\":\"message=BadRequest; errorCode=003202; statusCode=400\",\"detail\":\"Missing required parameter: access_token\",\"code\":\"3202\",\"element\":null}],\"type\":\"VALIDATION\"},\"report\":null,\"queryResponse\":null,\"batchItemResponse\":[],\"attachableResponse\":[],\"syncErrorResponse\":null,\"requestId\":null,\"time\":1603006472539,\"status\":null,\"cdcresponse\":[]}",
      "json":{
         "warnings":null,
         "intuitObject":null,
         "fault":{
            "error":[
               {
                  "message":"message=BadRequest; errorCode=003202; statusCode=400",
                  "detail":"Missing required parameter: access_token",
                  "code":"3202",
                  "element":null
               }
            ],
            "type":"VALIDATION"
         },
         "report":null,
         "queryResponse":null,
         "batchItemResponse":[
            
         ],
         "attachableResponse":[
            
         ],
         "syncErrorResponse":null,
         "requestId":null,
         "time":1603006472539,
         "status":null,
         "cdcresponse":[
            
         ]
      },
      "intuit_tid":"1-5f8bf008-0186e88168aa182213feefcf"
   },
   "originalMessage":"Response has an Error",
   "error":"Bad Request",
   "error_description":"Bad Request",
   "intuit_tid":"1-5f8bf008-0186e88168aa182213feefcf"
}
```

Comment: You have to provide accesstoken in your header

Comment: @Ashish I've fixed that error but now there is another error i've got. When i call the api i get a response of code 400